# Phase Portrait in ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If we have the system $X' = AX$ where $A=\pmatrix{0&-1\cr1&-4\cr}$

How can we find the general solution and construct a phase portrait?

What I do for the solution is get the characteristic polynomial, eigenvalues and see the sign of the eigenvalues. But then I am unsure how to accurately represnt it using a phase portrait even after getting the eigenvectors

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you indicate what you obtained for the characteristic polynomial and eigenvalues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the system $X' = AX$ where $A=\pmatrix{0&-1\cr1&-4\cr}$

You should get an Eigensystem as follows:

$$\lambda_1 = -2 - \sqrt{3}, v_1 = (+2 - \sqrt{3},~ 1)$$

$$\lambda_2 = -2 + \sqrt{3}, v_2 = (+2 + \sqrt{3},~ 1)$$

We can write the [*Jordan Normal Form*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) as:

$$A = P J P^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 - \sqrt{3} & 2 + \sqrt{3} \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} -2 - \sqrt{3} & 0  \\ 0 & -2 + \sqrt{3} \\ \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{3}} & -\frac{-2 - \sqrt{3}}{2 \sqrt{3}} \\ \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{3}} & -\frac{2 - \sqrt{3}}{2 \sqrt{3}} \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Next, we want to draw a phase portrait for this system. What sort of phase portrait do you get from the eigenvalues? Is it stable or unstable?

Can you draw a phase space diagram and then superimpose solutions from the eigenvalues/eigenvectors?

Since we have two distinct, real eigenvalues, the solution will be given by

$$x(t) = c_1e^{\lambda_1 t}v_1 + c_2e^{\lambda_2 t}v_2$$

Hint: Follow this [*example*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/RealEigenvalues.aspx).

I have attached an image showing the items above, but now you should do it analytically and it sounds like you have all of the information you need.

[image]

Regards

Comment: @ShaunAult: Thanks, surprising how many online Java scripts one can find to generate such things. These should be part of every course on ODEs.

Comment: OMG! how could you do this graph? Did you use Maple for that? If so give us the codes or a good link for that. +

Comment: @BabakSorouh: See both the free [*DFIELD and PPLANE*](http://math.rice.edu/~dfield/dfpp.html.

Comment: How gorgeous! I agree with Babak, OMG! +1

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks, these are fun problems and I love that they incorporate analytical, applied and graphical solutions.

Comment: @amWhy: Good morning! I am only $30$ away from my review queue goal! Thanks for the support. Time to shift gears to my other interests, including Zentangle, which i think you would like given I know you have done stuff with graphics and this artform uses a lot of symmetry. Have a great day, off to the gym and then some chores!